# sub domain cgi script

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cgi, subdomain

on my mutualized server (hosted by OVH), I have the following directories :
/cgi-bin (for my perl scripts)
/www (website html files)

for one specific URL (http://www.example.com/try), I call a CGI perl script to create the HTML page dynamically. For this purpose I created a .htaccess file under /www with the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule try /cgi-bin/try.pl
```

Everything works fine !

I recently tried to migrate my site to a sub domain : swift.example.com by creating /swift directory and copying/pasting everything from /www.
Of course I made all the DNS stuff under my site manager to have swift.mysite.com pointing to /swift.
All the static HTML navigation works fine but URL http://swift.example.com/try returns an Internal Server Error.

www being a sub domain such as as swift, why would it crash when both sub domains are identical ?

Thanks for your help.

Fred

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude the destination path you are rewriting to,Try :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cgi-bin
RewriteRule try /cgi-bin/try.pl [L]
```

Comment: Great thanks but now I get a "The requested URL /cgi-bin/try.pl was not found on this server." error for sub domain swift. Still works fine for www with your changes